# How to calculate $P (Y > X+1)$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Let the joint probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
$$f(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{align}
  & {{e}^{-(x+y)}}\quad,x>0\,\,,\,\,y>0 \\ 
 & 0\qquad\quad\,\,\,,\operatorname{o}.w \\ 
\end{align} \right.$$
I want to compute $P (Y > X+1)$ in the region $D$.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You just have to compute the integral of $e^{-(x+y)}$ over the given region, i.e.

$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{1+x}^{+\infty}e^{-(x+y)}\,dy\,dx =\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-1-2x}\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2e}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It was very  nice! 
For dummies: We can separate terms for the exponential function, namely,
$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \Big(\int_{1+x}^{+\infty} e^{-y} dy\Big)e^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{2e}.$

Answer (score 1):

If $X,Y$ are random variables that have a joint distribution characterized by PDF $f(x,y)$ then for every Borel-measurable set $A\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ we have:$$\Pr\left(\{\langle X,Y\rangle\in A\}\right)=\int\int \chi_A(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy$$

Here $\chi_A(x,y)$ denotes the indicator function of $A$.

Apply this on $A=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\mathbb R^2\mid y>x+1\}$.